# Compare two consecutive row data in a table in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table with 3 columns as TimeStamp , BidPrice & AskPrice.
I have to compare data from consecutive rows say 1st comparison of Row 1 & 2 and the next Row 2 & 3 and so on till the end of the table. When either the BidPrice or AskPrice of the rows don't match I have to dump differences of their time stamp into a different table with only one column as TimeStamp.

```
+---------------+------------+-----------+
| ExchTimeStamp | BidPrice0  | AskPrice0 |
+===============+============+===========+
| 1127918883925 | 58765      | 59395     |
+---------------+------------+-----------+
| 1127918883926 | 58765      | 59395     |
+---------------+------------+-----------+
| 1127918883965 | 58765      | 59390     |
+---------------+------------+-----------+
| 1127918884043 | 58765      | 59320     |
+---------------+------------+-----------+
| 1127918884050 | 58765      | 59315     |
+---------------+------------+-----------+
```

Table shown above is the sample data as I have to compare Row 1&2's Bid price since they are different I have to find the difference of  TimeStamp of these respective rows and insert that value into a new table say TimeStampData.

Expected Result

```
+---------------+
| TimeStamp     |
+===============+
| 0             |
+---------------+
| 39            | 
+---------------+
| 78            |
+---------------+
| 7             |
+---------------+
```

I am very much new to MySQL so required some help over it

Comment: Please update your question with the query you have, some sample data and an example of the desired output (based on the sample data)

Comment: @Lima  Edited for sample data ..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can do something like this

```
        ; WITH CTE AS  
          (SELECT Column1,Timstampcolumn,LAG(Timstampcolumn,1) OVER 
   (PARTITION BY Column1 ORDER BY Column1) AS OLD_TIMESTAMP FROM Yourtable 
    WHERE 'youruserid'

     )
      SELECT *,DATEDIFF(DD,OLD_TIMESTAMP,Timstampcolumn) 
      FROM CTE WHERE OLD_TIMESTAMP IS NOT NULL
```

where LAG 1 means you want to compare next row

Comment: thanks jayanti , but i didnt get how this wil compare 2 consicutive rows each time?

Comment: Sorry for late response..please find my edited solution this will work for you:)